# WMIC Output Result - Remove Blank Line?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, wmic

This script does what I want it to do - producing the result in the txt file noted.

```
(@for /F "delims=" %I in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get DriverVersion /VALUE') do @for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %J in ("%I") do @echo/%K) > "C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\GPU\DriverVersion.txt"
```

However, it seems to add an extra blank line at the bottom of the result. Is there any way I can stop this from happening as the line count result from this txt is very important?

Comment: The output file will contain the driver version info plus one line-break (CR + LF); does this final line-break disturb you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no extra blank line at the bottom of the result (proved using [`findstr.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)):

```
d:\bat> (@for /F "delims=" %I in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get DriverVersion /VALUE') do @for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %J in ("%I") do @echo/%K) > DriverVersion.txt

d:\bat> findstr /N "^" DriverVersion.txt
1:23.21.13.8813

d:\bat> findstr /N "$" DriverVersion.txt
1:23.21.13.8813
```

However, you can add an extra blank line at the bottom of the result as follows:

```
d:\bat> echo(>> DriverVersion.txt

d:\bat> findstr /N "^" DriverVersion.txt
1:23.21.13.8813
2:

d:\bat> findstr /N "$" DriverVersion.txt
1:23.21.13.8813
2:
```

Note meaning of the `/N` switch:

- `/N`   Print the line number before each line that matches.

and search patterns:

- `^`         Line position: beginning of line
- `$`         Line position: end of line

See also [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433/3439404): use `<nul set /p =%K` instead of `echo/%K`.

```
d:\bat> (@for /F "delims=" %I in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get DriverVersion /VALUE') do @for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %J in ("%I") do @<nul set /p =%K) > DriverVersion.txt

d:\bat> findstr /N "^" DriverVersion.txt
1:23.21.13.8813
d:\bat> findstr /N "$" DriverVersion.txt

d:\bat>
```